# How to remove or hide the google icon from the google translate api?

Tags: php, html, css, api, google-translate

I am using this line of code:

```
    <div id="google_translate_element"></div>
<script>
   function googleTranslateElementInit() {
      var translator = new google.translate.TranslateElement({
      pageLanguage: 'en',
      autoDisplay: false,
      multilanguagePage: false,
      layout: google.translate.TranslateElement.InlineLayout.SIMPLE
   }, 'google_translate_element');
}
</script>
<script src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>
```

Here is the output and I want to remove the icon, how can possibly remove it? or hide

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Used to this**

```
.goog-te-gadget-icon{
background:none !important;
}
```

***[Live Demo](http://tinkerbin.com/iZ1tDonV)***

Answer (score 3):

This is much better than rohit's answer

```
.goog-te-gadget-icon{
  display:none;
}
```

Comment: I would agree that this is the better answer since it doesn't leave a blank space where the icon was, which is what happens it you only remove the background, not the entire element.